# How do I get the temperature of my USB Miner?

Tags: mining-hardware, cgminer, bfgminer, alert-system

Is there an option I can pass when running the miner? ( CGMiner / BFGMiner )

How does one get the temperature of a USB Miner? ( In my case BitFury )

Comment: Have you considered using an external device such as an infrared thermometer?

Comment: @GregHewgill to my understanding this USB Miner has a temperature sensor already, I just wanted to know how to access it

Answer (score 1):

If your device has a temp sensor it will show in the API output and in the Text User Interface that is default when running at the command line

Comment: I don't see it though, is there an option to pass to display this information?

Comment: if you don't see it your device probably doesn't have a temperature sensor - most usb stick miners do not